# Is there a way to make frequency include business days but without (US) holidays in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series, frequency

I'm trying to generate a `pandas.DataFrame` with all the 'trading days' in 2017, essentially business days minus holidays.  Alternatively, I could make a `list` (from another `pandas.DataFrame`, called 'dates' for arguments sake.) and pass that but not quite sure how.

Below is code of what I am currently generating, but holidays are included.

```
new_fut = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = '2017-1-1', end = '2018-1-1',  freq = 'b'), columns = ['ds'])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go. this will take out all the holidays from Custom Business Day.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
start ='2017-1-1'
end = '2018-1-1'
us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
df=pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start,end=end, freq=us_bd)

df
```

Comment: I had to remove the hashtag and eliminate the line after the hashtagged line but that seemed to work.  Thank you, going to list this as answered, but you may want to edit.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but I could not make it work with darts.TimeSeries.from_dataframe. Looks like darts does not like custom business day frequency.

Comment: what error message do you get? you can create a new question with your script/output and then point us to it.

Answer (score 2):

Check with `bdate_range` with your self-define holidays' list (`yourlist`)

```
pd.bdate_range(start='2017-1-1', end='2018-1-1',holidays = yourlist)
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with bdate_range (time series is very new to me).  Are you suggesting I manually add US holidays (my list has all the weekday non-holiday dates) or is there an automated Python function for US holidays of some sort.

Comment: @Zonk US holiday ...it is depends on you need Federal or all holiday (like good friday), So I would like suggest define it by yourself rather than using the code auto pop up, since this will have more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

Pandas supports custom holiday and also has a built in USFederalHolidayCalendar that would probably meets your needs.

You can find more here:

> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Scroll down to Holidays/Holiday Calendars
under DateOffset objects